# Terminology for secret sharing?

Tags: secret-sharing, terminology, threshold-cryptography

To my understanding, there are two "approaches" to *t out of n* threshold encryption. In both of them, *n* shares are given to different shareholders, and at least *t* of them must agree to "proceed". "Proceed" can take two different meanings: either the shares are the input to derive a secret that can be used to perform a traditional decryption (e.g. Shamir) or the shareholders produce a partial encryption that can be put together to generate the decryption (e.g. Damgård-Jurik).

I have found the first scenario to be known as *secret sharing*, but I am looking for a term to describe the second approach unambiguously. Does such term exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is strong enough precedence for using the term **threshold decryption** for the second.

The abstract of [this paper](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~franklin/ijact.pdf) states:

> A threshold decryption scheme is a multi-party public key cryptosystem that allows any sufficiently large subset of participants to decrypt a ciphertext, but disallows the decryption otherwise.

Sounds to me like what you are talking about. A search for ["threshold decryption"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22threshold+decryption%22) turns up plenty of hits too.

Comment: Perhaps it's more common to call it "Threshold encryption"? See for instance [this paper by Boneh et al.](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/ibethresh.pdf). Anyway, I admit that "threshold decryption" is more precise, technically speaking.

Comment: @cygnusv Yeah, I've seen Threshold Encryption before too. Probably either works just as well.

Comment: A scheme supporting this is a "threshold encryption scheme" -- i.e., an encryption scheme of the threshold variety -- or just "threshold encryption" for short. But since the threshold part only comes into play during decryption, it's fine to refer to that process as "threshold decryption"